# Lists are mutable but tuples are immutable, then how is the value of x changed when running function tuple?

Tags: python

I wrote 2 functions to try and understand the difference between immutable and mutable, one of the functions has a variable assigned to a list the other one is assigned to a tuple. After running the first function ( in the case of the list) it prints the updated value of x, but that wasn't supposed to happen for tuples because tuples are immutable right? How come they both print the updated x.

list

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

def changeThem(x,y,z):
    return [z if i == y else i for i in x]

print(changeThem(x, 2, 'zzz'))
```

tuple

```
x = ("apple", "banana", "cherry")

def changeThem(x,y,z):
    return [z if i == y else i for i in x]

print(changeThem(x, "apple", 'zzz'))
```

Comment: It does not change the tuple, it returns a new list.

Comment: In both cases you return a new list; in neither case is the input mutated, even though the list could be, and it doesn't matter what kind of iterable `x` happens to be.

Comment: You mutated no objects *in either case*

Comment: how can i change my code to not make it return a new list rather to update it?@jonrsharpe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see this example.

```
x_list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
x_tuple = (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)


def change_them_comprehension(x, y, z):
    return [z if i == y else i for i in x]


def change_them_manual(x, y, z):
    for idx, i in enumerate(x):
        if i == y:
            x[idx] = z
    return x


print("list")
print(id(x_list))  # 1877716860160
print(id(change_them_comprehension(x_list, 2, 'zzz')))  # 1877716698368
print(id(change_them_manual(x_list, 2, 'zzz')))  # 1877716860160


print("tuple")
print(id(x_tuple))  # 1877716262336
print(id(change_them_comprehension(x_tuple, 2, 'zzz')))  # 1877716698368
print(id(change_them_manual(x_tuple, 2, 'zzz')))  # TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Notice how your `change_them` returns a new list comprehension, which is an absolutely different list from the original one (see they have different ids). This does not involve mutation; instead of editing the list you return a new list (in both the original tuple and original list cases).

Now check `change_them_manual`. This method does edit the input list/tuple and not creates a new one. See how the returned list is the same (same id). We can edit it because lists are mutable. However, when we try to do the same with the tuple we get an error, which tells us we can't edit the tuple, this is what not being mutable means.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable in this way:

```
x = ("apple", "banana", "cherry")
x[0]='ananas'
```

**TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment**

In your second example, you're not changing the tuple.
Instead, you are defining new variable which is a list.

Answer (score 1):

It's better you understand what you are trying to do here. The function you created is creating a new list. If you print out your x, you will see that it has not been changed.

Here are a couple of docs/articles that might help you get a better understanding of mutable vs. immutable...
[python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) and [real python explanation](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/)

Good luck exploring python!